# Do not apply _ViewStart to child actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My _ViewStart sets Layout property. It worked fine untill I started to use child actions - in this case Layout is applied both for main action and for child. Is there any way to deny applying _ViewStart (or at least Layout) to child actions?

Comment: Are you rendering child actions with `View()` or `PartialView()`?

Comment: That is the code in your view - is the action method you are invoking returning a View or partial view? It sounds like you are returning a View from your Html.Action call.

Comment: @Tejs, PartialView helped, thank you. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make sure you child action renders a PartialView:

AKA

```
 @Html.Action("YourActionMethodName");
```

The code would look like so:

```
 public ActionResult YourActionMethodName()
 {
      return PartialView();
 }
```